# Esky patching procedure

Tags: esky

I'm trying to auto update using [Esky](http://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/) differential patches, but I haven't been able to get the app to update using *only* those differential patches. It seems like a full version is always needed for a correct update.

So, if I have version 0.1 and patches plus full file versions up to 0.3 in the updates server, the client app will fetch *both* the patches AND the full latest version file:

```
updatesServer/
  App-0.1.win32.zip (client version running)
  App-0.2.win32.zip (this isn't fetched)
  App-0.2.win32.from-0.1.patch (this is fetched first)
  App-0.3.win32.zip (this is fetched third)
  App-0.3.win32.from-0.2.patch (this is fetched second)
```

Also, if the latest version weren't to be available (App-0.3.win32.zip in this case), the update would fail.

The [behavior](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/tree/master/tutorial) I would expect is for Esky to get the patch file and update while ignoring the other full file version available so the update is blazing fast. Is there a way to achieve this?

Environment info: the freezer I'm using is cx_freeze and my Python version is 3.4.

Update-routine code:

```
from esky import *
from esky.util import appexe_from_executable

def restart_this_app():
    appexe = appexe_from_executable(sys.executable)
    os.execv(appexe,[appexe] + sys.argv[1:])

if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
    app = esky.Esky(sys.executable, UPDATES_URL)
    print("You are running version "+app.active_version)
    print("Looking for updates...")
    if app.find_update() is None:
        print("No updates have been found.")
    else:
        print("Updates available. Updating...")
        try:
            app.auto_update()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error while updating:", e)
        else:
            print("Update complete.")
            print("Restarting app...")
            time.sleep(3)
            restart_this_app()
```

BTW, this is my first StackOverflow question ever. Thank you for taking a look at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This patch](https://github.com/JPFrancoia/esky/commit/615bd8e85356b0bb67192c22501897f8d3a5a72d) is a potential short term fix for the issue.

Please give it a go and let the developers know if it works for you.

Comment: My out-of-the-shelf esky pip 0.9.9 install was kind of outdated, so I installed esky 0.9.10.dev0 from the official repo for the patch to be there. However, the issue persists. I'll try helping squash the bug.

Comment: The patch isn't applied yet because we still don't know what's causing the issue(no time), The exception is only getting raised when installing patches from remote urls. https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/issues/113

Comment: Also, could you tell us what OS you're using ? On OSX for example, updates from the patches alone don't work. I've been able to use the patches for Linux and Windows, but I have to admit, I didn't make them compete (only the patches were present on the server).

Comment: @Rififi I'm generating the bdist_esky executable from a WinXP Virtualbox VM and testing the updates from there as well, pointing to an updates server on my host OSX machine running plain http.server with Python3.4. What version were you using for the Linux and Windows differential patches to work? That would work for me, at least for a while.